# Tensor product of two polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am trying to show that $A[T_1] \otimes_A A[T_2] \simeq A[T_1,T_2]$, for ANY RING A. I defined a map $f:A[T_1] \otimes_A A[T_2] \rightarrow A[T_1,T_2]$ such that $p \otimes q = pq$. I was able to prove that $f(1) = 1$ and $f(0) =0$, but I'm having serious troubles to show injective and surjective.

I tried to show $f$ is injective this way: $f(p \otimes q) = f(p \otimes q') \Rightarrow f(p \otimes q) - f(p \otimes q) = 0 \Rightarrow f((p\otimes q)-(p\otimes q')) = f(p\otimes (q-q')) = p(q-q') =0$, but I can not assure that $q=q'$, since $A$ is, not necessarily, an integral domain.

To show surjective, it would be equivalent (I think) say that every polynomial of $A[T_1,T_2]$ can be factorized in a product of two polynomials from $A[T_1]$ and $A[T_2]$, which I do not think it is right.

My questions are:
1) What am I missing?
2) Did I took the wrong way to show the isomorphism?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try writing down the inverse map in the converse direction?

Comment: See Theorem 4.9 and Example 4.12 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf to see the map you give is an $A$-*module* isomorphism. In Example 7.7 of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf the same map (already a module isomorphism, so injective and surjective) is upgraded to an $A$-*algebra* isomorphism.

Comment: And there's an abstract non-sense argument: One observes that the left-hand-side is the coproduct and the right hand side is the free object in the category of $A$-algebras. Now the free functor is left adjoint to the forgetful functor and as a left adjoint functor it preserves coproducts.

Comment: @Antonio Henrique Your map is correct, but one thing you're forgetting is that elements in the tensor product are *linear combinations* of elementary tensors $p(T_1)\otimes q(T_2)$. Not every element in $A[T_1,T_2]$ can be written as a product $p(T_1)q(T_2)$, like you said, but every element can be written as a finite sum of such terms. This will deal with surjectivity

Comment: @NathanLowry Nice idea. It realy solved surjectivity problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a general fact: Let $R$ be a ring and $R \to S$ a $R$-algebra. Let $R[X]$ be a polynomial ring in one underminant $X$. Then $R[X] \otimes_R S= S[X]$. Take $R=A, S=A[T_2], X=T_1$.

Comment: How do you prove it?

Comment: @AntonioHenrique Let $f$ be an element of $R[x] \otimes_R S$, then $f$ is a finite linear combination of terms of the form $(a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n) \otimes s$ with $a_0 \in R$, $s \in S$. Expand this term linearly to $a_0 \otimes s + a_1 x \otimes s + \cdots + a_nx^n \otimes s$. Since the tensor product is over $R$, the $a_i$ can move over to the right hand side, so our sum becomes $1 \otimes a_0s + x \otimes a_1 s + \cdots +x^n \otimes a_n s$. From this representation, the isomorphism you want should be immediate.

Comment: @failedentertainment may I ask you to clarify the isomorphism?